# Reviewing small code (that isn't mine) for safety purposes

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a piece of code that is supposed to replace a native (PHP) function that is only available in a future version (newer than the one I can have).

As it is about cryptography/security, I should be 100% sure about it ideally.

I'm not sure where to post on SE, I considered the following:

- SO: I'm not sure but it doesn't feel like the most appropriate.
- SE codereview: It IS code review but not exactly what code review is for, right? Like this one is more about security/crypto.
- I know there is another sub-SE based on security/crypto (which I forgot the name) but I don't think they really are into code reviewing but I might be wrong.

Just so it is dealt with, this is about this snippet: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php#115664 (Which is also length safe, unlike the official one).

Comment: For the third, I think you mean either [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/), but I don't know either of them well enough to say if this would be on-topic there.

Comment: codereview.se only allows code written by yourself.

Comment: What's your question?  If you wanted to post a hunk of code and ask if it looks good (i.e., ask if it is secure), that is probably not going to be a good fit for Information Security or Cryptography (those sites aren't intended as a service for outsourcing code review -- if that's what you want, hire a professional).  Is there some other specific technical question you have?  That will probably determine whether it is on-topic for Information Security and/or Cryptography.